# Lines from points to plot axes

Tags: graph, plotly, settings

Please tell me! Is it possible to somehow add lines to the points that go to the axes of the graph, as shown in the figure? You can, of course, do it manually. I searched the documentation but did not find

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything in Plotly that can automatically add such annotations. However, you can do this manually in a dynamic way by creating a function that takes in each point to which you want to add vertical and horizontal lines.

Below I have recreated a similar piecewise function to the one you have displayed (logistic + horizontal line segment), hidden the yaxis, and used annotations to display the yaxis at x=0 on the figure, and added horizontal and vertical lines to each point of interest.

```
import numpy as np
from math import e
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

## reproduce your piecewise function
x1 = np.linspace(-1,1,500)
y1 = 1 / (1 + e**(2.5*(1.5-x1)))

x2 = np.linspace(1,1.5,500)
y2 = [0.5]*500

x3 = np.linspace(1.5,3,500)
y3 = 1 / (1 + e**(5*(1.0-x3)))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x1,y=y1,line=dict(color="red")))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1],y=[0.5],mode='markers',line=dict(color="red")))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x2,y=y2,line=dict(color="red")))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[x3[0]],y=[y3[0]],mode='markers',line=dict(color="red")))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x3,y=y3,line=dict(color="red")))
fig.update_layout(template="simple_white", showlegend=False)

## remove yaxis but set the range
fig.update_yaxes(range=[0, 1.1], visible=False)

## add custom yaxis at x=0
fig.add_vline(x=0, line_width=1, line_color="black")
for y_tick in np.linspace(0,1,6):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=[-0.01,0.01],
        y=[y_tick]*2,
        mode="lines+text",
        name=None,
        hoverinfo='none',
        text=[f'{y_tick:.1f}'],
        textposition="top left",
        line=dict(color="black", width=1)
    ))

## function to add horizontal and vertical lines for points
def add_horizontal_and_vertical_lines(fig, x_val, y_val):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=[x_val]*2,
        y=[0,y_val],
        mode="lines",
        hoverinfo='none',
        line=dict(color="grey", width=0.5)
    ))
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=[0,x_val],
        y=[y_val]*2,
        mode="lines",
        hoverinfo='none',
        line=dict(color="grey", width=0.5)
    ))

## loop through the points of interest
for x_point,y_point in zip([x1[-1],x1[-1],x2[-1],x2[-1],x3[-1]],[y1[-1],y2[0],y2[-1],y3[0],y3[-1]]):
    add_horizontal_and_vertical_lines(fig, x_point, y_point)

fig.show()
```

[image]